# Routing in Kohana without showing controller name

Tags: kohana-3.3

I want to create a routing in Kohana Framework Version 3.3.1.

I want URL like http://www.test.com/male/London and internally they will act like below URL-

http://www.test.com/list/search/London

I want to hide the controller and action name from the URL.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be accomplished by using routes in bootstrap.php and/or a module's init.php file.

For example, you could set up a route for `(male/<location>)` and then your default controller would be `list` and the action `search`.

You could then access the location within the controller/action by using `$this->request->param('location');` to be used in whatever DB query you need it.

Confused? Have a read through this section of [Kohana Docs](https://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/kohana/routing) and it should all make sense.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do two changes in your file:

- 1. Bootstarp file :

     ```
     Route::set('list', 'male/<id>' )
     ->defaults(array(
     'controller' => 'list',
     'action'     => 'search',
     ));`
     ```
- 2. And second is you can make your link like

     ```
     href="<?php echo URL::site('male/'.id, TRUE) ?>">
     ```

And this route file should above at your default route file.